# How to cluster a dataframe by column of long vectors

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a train dataframe that has a feature named 'address' and feature called 'vecor' that have vectors that are 700 lengthed which contains information of addresses(there were 700 different columns that for every address that I converted them to a single long vector). I want to cluster these addresses by vector column but when I try to use KMeans algorithm,

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
x = np.array(train['vector'].values).astype('float64')
ms = KMeans(n_clusters=3,n_init=10,max_iter=300,random_state=42)
ms.fit(x)
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-919881bf72d4> in <module>
      1 from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
----> 2 x = np.array(train['vector'].values).astype('float64')
      3 ms = KMeans(n_clusters=3,n_init=10,max_iter=300,random_state=42)
      4 ms.fit(x)
      5 cluster_centers = ms.cluster_centers_

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

As it is impossible to use all 700 columns before being converted to vectors, and this method is not working too, Do you have any advice?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `train` is a dataframe? Shouldn't you use values?

```
ms.fit(train['vector'].values)
```

Comment: yes train is my training dataframe. using values doesn't make any difference.still get above error

Comment: have you changed dtype to float?